# How to use Windows START with cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, process

i would like to set the priority of a command-line statement, such as `copy test.txt test2.txt`

i found the Windows [`START`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) command, which allows to set priority of an executable. [more info](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-Command-Prompt&faq=12)

So i assume i need to pass `cmd.exe` to START.

But this is not working:

```
START /LOW "mycopy" "cmd.exe copy test.txt test4.txt"
```

It returns: `The system cannot find the file cmd.exe copy test.txt test4.txt.`

The following opens a new empty command window, and the copy does not happen:

```
START /LOW "mycopy" "cmd ""copy test.txt test4.txt"""
```

The following returns `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`, and the copy does not happen.

```
START /LOW "mycopy" /B cmd.exe "copy test.txt test4.txt"
```

nor other variations of single, double, or double-double quoting.

How can this be achieved? (simpler is better :)

Prefer if the new command window closes itself after executing.

ps, i'm also open to methods involving PowerShell.

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` syntax is basically:

```
start cmd_to_run argument to cmd
```

Since you quoted the entire command, you're literally trying to run a program whose filename is `cmd.exe copy ....`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Just remove those quotes:

```
start /low "mycopy" cmd copy test.txt test4.txt
                     ^-command to run
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- arguments to command
```

The ONLY time you'd have to quote the command itself is if you're including a path that contains spaces in the filename, or the program name itself contains spaces, e.g.

```
start c:\program files\foo\bar.exe /hi /mom
      ^^^^^^^^^^---program  (no such file/command)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ arguments to this bad command
```

v.s.

```
start "c:\program files\foo\bar.exe" /hi /mom
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--command
                                     ^^^^^^^^---arguments
```

Comment: You don't even need `cmd`. This works: `start /low "Copying" copy test.txt txt4.txt`

Comment: @KenWhite, i prefer this simpler syntax! You deserve special mention for that. But the new command window remains open with this syntax, which i don't want.

Comment: @johnywhy: That is not mentioned anywhere at all in your question, but yes - if you want the command window to close you'll need the `cmd /c` (you don't need the `.exe`, by the way).

Comment: @KenWhite, right you are. I added the preference for the window to close itself. Thx for telling i can remove the `.exe`.

Comment: I only put in the .exe to make it visually clear where pathing stops and arguments start.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all this quoting or `start` thinks this is the sole argument: the command itself.

This works:

```
START /LOW "mycopy" cmd.exe /c copy test.txt test4.txt
```

Note the `/c` argument which tells `cmd` to execute the following command.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoiseFabre, you're equally deserving of win, but chosen answer gives a bit more info on quoting, which is where i was stuck. Thx!

Comment: thanks. I think that `start /low "mycopy" cmd copy test.txt test4.txt` does not work at all: it does not copy `test.txt` in `test4.txt` (missing /c seems to do that)

Comment: i think we can leave out `.exe` or `/c`, not both, but have not tested. (i wonder why your name does not popup with the @ symbol in this comment box)

Comment: @johnywhy Because he wrote the answer (and therefore get notified of all comments anyway).

Comment: @DavidPostill, thx for explaining. I think notification is only half the benefit of name-popup. The other benefit is, it reduces typing and misspellings by commenter. For that reason, i think SO should include name-popups for answerer-names, not just commenter-names. My 2 ¢  :)